# IIS display {{title}} Dashboard Heroes rather than dynamic page

Tags: angular, iis, deployment

When I deploy toh with IIS, I have this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu2B3.png) rather than normal page.
Anybody have an idea about my problem?

Thanks you very much,

Augustin

I tried to deploy the application : https://indepth.dev/posts/1239/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis

Comment: is it working locally without iis? When you run with ng serve does it display 'title' correctly?

Comment: You should be missing some configuration information, use the F12 developer tool or Event View to view related error messages.